# ซอย สามเสน thai langauge is showing black box in pdf

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-generation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPuld.png)

Some Thai char is showing in browser and email properly but when open generated wkpdf file in email its showing black box.

Comment: Welcome! Could you add some minimal reproducible code? In that way it's easier for us to help you out.

Comment: Please share your code about it and what are you already done in it.